# python decorator causes dict of kwargs of a function to be treated as positional arguments

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I am experimenting with writing decorator functions in python3.I wrote a simple function that takes any number of positional and named arguments as below

```
def function(*args,**kwargs):
    print('\nin function')
    for arg in args:
        print('arg=',arg)
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        print(k,'=',v)
```

when I call this function

```
function('damon','julian',age=36,score=100)
```

I get the expected result

```
in function
arg= damon
arg= julian
score = 100
age = 36
```

Then I wrote a decorator maker function with which I can create a decorator

```
def make_decorator(*dargs,**dkwargs):
    def deco(f):
        def wrapper(*fargs,**fkwargs):
            print('\nin decorator:wrapper')
            print('dargs=',dargs)
            print('dkwargs=',dkwargs)
            f(fargs,fkwargs)
        return wrapper
    return deco
```

I decorated my function with this,

```
@make_decorator('D1','D2',name='deco')
def function(*args,**kwargs):
    print('\nin function')
    for arg in args:
        print('arg=',arg)
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        print(k,'=',v)
```

when I call the function ,I get this result

```
in decorator:wrapper
dargs= ('D1', 'D2')
dkwargs= {'name': 'deco'}

in function
arg= ('damon', 'julian')
arg= {'age': 36, 'score': 100}
```

I understand the output from the wrapper.But,why is the output from my function treats the dict of the named arguments as another positional argument?I was expecting an output like

```
score = 100
age = 36
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Because you call `f(fargs,fkwargs)` not `f(*fargs, **fkwargs)`; you are passing the tuple of positional arguments and dictionary of keyword arguments as two positional arguments.